# How can I reset the USB overcurrent protection in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, usb

I attach a USB device to the Mac, which I otherwise know is quite power hungry (eats more than 200 mA @ 9V). So I plug this in the Mac (OSX 10.5.8), and get a:

> USB Over Current Notice.
>
> A USB device is currently drawing too much power.
>   The hub it is attached to will be deactivated.

Good enough – it is almost something I had expected..

So I add external power to the device, and I try to plug it in again - and Mac OSX doesn't react. Again, as expected, since the dialog said: "*The hub it is attached to will be deactivated*".

However, now it seems that I'd have to reboot the Mac from the start, to test this device's connection now that it has external power. And of course, I would like to avoid restarting, so my question is – is there a software way, for me to "reset"/"stop" this "overcurrent protection", and bring the USB port it is connected to again in the normal/default/activated state?

EDIT: Now I tried plugging it a few times more - without restarting - and strangely, it started working... What I did was `tail -f /var/log/system.log`, and then could see USB related messages realtime.. So maybe to redefine my question - is there a (default) way to monitor and check, whether the USB overcurrent protection is active for a given port/hub?

Comment: What exactly are you plugging in that is 9V? USB is only 5V.

Comment: Why are people so against restarting?

Comment: @Ramhound; Sometimes you can't reboot, knowing how to do things the right way, rather than the easy way, is important too

Comment: @James - it's an Arduino with a custom analog preamplifier shield, powered by 9V (the 200 mA, I measured from output of this source - I didn't intend to refer to USB's 5V, sorry about the misunderstanding)

Comment: @Ramhound - in this case, I have to start up and monitor several scripts manually (they don't lend themselves being called from a single script), which takes some time, which I'd like to avoid losing.